# Uncheck radio button inside Razor Component

Tags: razor, radio-button, blazor

I'm creating radio buttons like this inside a Razor component:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int answerIndex = i;
    <input type="radio" @onclick="(() => Answer(answerIndex))"/> @options[i]
    <br />
}
```

I would like for the button I clicked to get unchecked inside the Answer() function but I can't find a way to bind the checked property to a variable.

I have tried to do checked=@boolean but when I check it the boolean doesn't change nor does it get unchecked when I change the boolean.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0#radio-buttons

Comment: @BrianParker I can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: You are supposed to use two-way binding, your solution is only one way: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0). The link of @BrianParker is about using built-in Blazor components (`InputRadioGroup` and `InputRadio`), another way of coding your solution.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine does it allow two way binding for the checked property or some way to uncheck it manually?

Comment: @Tommaso Two-way binding allows you to modify/instanciate the value as you wish and to let the user update the value from UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo page showing how to bind to a Radio buttons using the built in `InputRadioGroup` control.  I've also switched to a `foreach` to avoid index problems.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value=_selectedCountry>
    @foreach (var country in _countries)
    {
        <div>
            <InputRadio Value="country" />
            @country
        </div>
    }
</InputRadioGroup>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.ClearValue>Clear</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Country : @(_selectedCountry ?? "Not Set")</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private string? _selectedCountry;

    public List<string> _countries = new()
    {
        "UK",
        "France",
        "Spain"
    };

    public void ClearValue()
        => _selectedCountry = null;
}
```

Or if you want to use objects:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value=_selectedCountryUid>
    @foreach(var country in _countries)
    {
        <div>
            <InputRadio Value="country.Uid" />
            @country.Name
        </div>
    }
</InputRadioGroup>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.ClearValue>Clear</button>
</div>
<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Country : @(_selectedCountry?.Name ?? "Not Selected")</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private Guid? _selectedCountryUid;
    private Country? _selectedCountry => _countries.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uid.Equals(_selectedCountryUid));

    public List<Country> _countries = new()
    {
        new( Guid.NewGuid(), "UK"),
        new( Guid.NewGuid(), "France"),
        new( Guid.NewGuid(), "Spain")
    };

    public void ClearValue()
        => _selectedCountryUid = null;

    public record Country(Guid Uid, string Name); 
}
```

Comment: great thanks, however if i clear the bound string (setting it to null or empty string) the option still shows visually, how can i make it disappear?

Comment: See the revised answer that adds a button to clear the value.